# How to pass the process.env to the child process in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

On clicking a button i was trying to open windows file explorer. My node js code for this-

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

        var cmdString = 'start '+'C:/myApp/dropbox/';
        const child = exec(cmdString,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {

            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        })
```

If i start my application from command line, its working fine.
If i start my application using service, it don't work in this case.

After a lot of investigation, i came to know that we need to pass to pass the process.env at the time we are executing the command.

**Can anyone tell me how i can pass the process.env to the child process.**

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback `env` option

Comment: @dandavis  you mean this - {env: {'HOME': 'process.env["USERPROFILE"]'}

Comment: yes, you can map like that. maybe `{env: process.env}` would pass all at once?

Comment: this {env: process.env} did not work

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do?   The whole point of environment variables is that they're _automatically_ passed from parent process to child process.   However you also say you want to start your application "using service".   Do you means as a Windows Service?  Those typically don't have access to interactive windows.

Comment: From the child process, I want to execute command- start C:/myApp/dropbox/ to open the file explorer. Its work fine if i start the application from cmd. But if i start it from services, it dont. my question is what else need to pass in the child process.

Comment: Ok so make a file named .env like this: MYVAR = 'abcd'    , further reading:  https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-2cb45a55195f